# Loading a different google map everytime, after clicking different address

Tags: dictionary

In my website I have two panel, left side is for adrress and right side is for google map.
I want to load a google map once I click a particular address without page refresh. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement this via Javascript, the algorithm will be something like this:

1. Show a map based on a default location (e.g. your city and adequate zoom level to this)
2. a form with a textbox to search and address
3. An event on click on a "search button" to geocode and get a lat,lon for that address
4. Re-set via Javascript the center of the map based on the geocode service response
5. add a marker on location returned from geocoding service.

hope this helps

PD How are you querying the map with the panels right now ?

Answer (score 0):

Geocode the address here is the link on how to go about it
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests

then do this 
map.setMap(latLng)
where map is your global map object 
and latLng is co-ordinates obtained from geocode library

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>

var geocoder;

var map;

function initialize() {

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

  var mapOptions = {zoom: 8,center: latlng

  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {

  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

          map: map,

          position: results[0].geometry.location

      });

    } 
else
 {

      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);

   }

  });

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



    </script>

 <input id="address" type="textbox" value="New Delhi, India">

      <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
```